# unable to delete .Trash on external drive (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: nautilus, ntfs, trash

I am unable to remove my files from `.Trash/` folder on my external hard drive.
The file system is `NTFS`. Files are not in use by any process, therefore might not be locked.

`Empty Trash` menu entry on the trash icon opens an empty file manager, endlessly loading the list of files.

When launching nautilus with sudo it displays:

```
This location could not be displayed. 
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "Trash:///": Operation not supported
```

`sudo rm -rf /path/to/.Trash-1000/*` results in

```
cannot access '.Trash-1000/expunged/2836763541/timing': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '.Trash-1000/expunged/2358660437': Directory not empty
...
```

What can I do to empty `.Trash/` folder on external drive?